# Why do we define the Doléan measure of a continuous square-integrable martingale only on the predictable sets?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

If $M$ is a continuous square-integrable martingale on a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,(\mathcal F_t)_{t\in[0,\:T]}\operatorname P)$ and $[M]$ denotes the quadratic variation of $M$, then $$\alpha_M(E):=\operatorname E\left[\int1_E\:{\rm d}[M]\right]\;\;\;\text{for }E\in\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal B((0,T])\tag1$$ is a well-defined finite measure on $\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal B((0,T])$.

$\alpha_M$ is called the *Doléan measure* of $M$. Usually, $\alpha_M$ is defined only on the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal P\subseteq\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal B((0,T])$ of $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\in[0,\:T]}$-predictable subsets of $\Omega\times(0,T]$.

> I've read in a lecture note, without any further comment, that while (as I wrote) $(1)$ is well-defined on $\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal B((0,T])$, we need to restrict the domain of $\alpha_M$ to $\mathcal P$, because "$(1)$ does not always provide the right extension", when we want to extend $\alpha_M$ beyond $\mathcal P$.
>
> What does the author mean? Is there a problem in a later stage of the construction of the stochastic integral?

Comment: A heuristical answer may be that if you integrate from time $n$ to time $n+1$, you should only use the information of time $n$. So you cannot look into future. You know what is now at time $n$, that is $f(n)$, and by random, an integration process, you get the integral $f(n) \times (M_{n+1} - M_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is *uniqueness*: $\alpha_M$ (restricted to $\mathcal P$) is the unique measure on $\mathcal P$ such that $\alpha_M(F\times(s,t])=\operatorname E[F(M_t^2-M_s^2)]$ for all $0<s\le t\le T$ and bounded $\mathcal F_s$-measurable $F$.

Under certain conditions, $\alpha_M$ admits a unique extention to the $\sigma$-algebra of progressively measurable sets; see Chapter 3 of *Introduction to Stochastic Integration* (2nd edition) by Chung and Williams.

Comment: p.s. The name is "Doléans"

Comment: So, the point is that (in general) the extension of $\left.\alpha_M\right|_{\mathcal P}$ to $\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal B((0,T])$ is not unique, right? But why is that an issue?

Comment: You want an object that is determined by the martingale alone.